# How to write a URL to resource from a different port in JavaScript without host name

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, url, websocket

My webapp serves at port 8090 and I want to use WebSocket at port 8091. Currently I use `var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8091')` on local test machine. If the webapp goes online, I should replace it with real hostname. Otherwise the request will be sent to local machine, not the real server, won't it?

I'd like to know, if it is possible to use something like `ws://:8091`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use a relative URL with just the port number. But you can do this:

```
"ws://"+document.location.hostname+":8091"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got you wrong but why don't you just do the following thing:

```
if(online){
 var between = "whatever";
}else{
 var between = "localhost";
}

new WebSocket('ws://' + between + ':8091');
```